# Latex rendering errors (not smooth) on macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, ipad, safari, ventura

When I enter LaTeX code into Typora, it renders incorrectly, as shown in the image below, with many jagged patterns:

[image]

This also happens when I am browsing with Safari, but Chrome works correctly:

[image]

Besides, Safari can render correctly some other pages:

[image]

I am completely confused by the above issue and considering to reset my system as this issue has not been recurring on my other Mac with macOS Monterey. This's my last resort to solve it. What could the underlying reason be and could there be any other way to fix it?

Update: I also had this issue with my iPad Pro after updating to iPadOS 16.

[image]

Could this problem be related to the way LaTeX renders? For example, different JavaScript libraries being used for different pages? Or related to the Retina screen (with high resolution)?

Comment: Is the rendered object text in a webpage? Or a graphic image of text?

Comment: https://github.com/typora/typora-issues/issues/5441
I think my issue has same reason as above.

Comment: If the suggestion in the link were to solve your problem, it would be great if you  could describe in an answer to your own question how that suggestion has helped you solve the problem.